# MIPS recursive function not working properly

Tags: recursion, mips, factorial

I'm doing a factorial recursive function in MIPS. Here is the code:

```
fact: #a1 = n   a2 = res

addi $t1,$zero,1
beq $a1,$t1,end  # if n == 1 return res
#else
mul $a2,$a2,$a1
subi $a1,$a1,1

jal fact


end:
sb $a2,res
jr $ra
```

The problem is, this code only works when i write `j fact` instead of `jal fact`, with `jal fact` the code run infinitely for some reason.

Comment: Single step and watch what happens.  Try it with the smallest possible recursive example, i.e. n=2.

Comment: Keep in mind that each `jal` will overwrite the previous value of `$ra` with the new return address. So if you want to preserve the previous return address you must do so yourself, e.g. by temporarily placing it on the stack.

Answer (score 0):

```
    fact: #a1 = n   a2 = res

addi $t1,$zero,1
beq $a1,$t1,end  # if n == 1 return res
#else
addi $sp, $sp, 8
sw $a1, 0($sp) #  in the top of the stack store the argument you called fact
sw $ra, 4($sp) # ra holds the return adress ( I do not know whether you know it)
mul $a2,$a2,$a1
subi $a1,$a1,1
jr $ra

jal fact
lw $a1, 0($sp) # load the value from memory adress that the top stack pointer shows to back to the register a1
lw $ra, 4($sp) 
addi $sp, $sp, 8 # delete current top , top-1 from the stack
jr $ra

end:
sb $a2,res
jr $ra
```